# How to pass radio button list parameters into C# from HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a HTML code of :

```html
 <form method="POST" action="FeedBack.aspx.cs">

        <div class="container">
            <h2>FeedBack Area</h2>

  <br />

    <h4>Comfort</h4>
    <br />
    
        <form role="form">
            <label class="radio-inline" name="radio1">
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="optradio1">Bad
            </label>

             <label class="radio-inline">
                 <input type="radio" value="2" name="optradio2">Good
            </label>

            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" value="3" name="optradio3">Excellent
            </label>
            <br />
        </form>
     </form>
```

And a C# code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string r1, r2, r3, r4;

        r1=string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["radio1"]);
        r2=string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["radio2"]);
        r3=string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["radio3"]);
        r4=string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["radio4"]);



        FeedBackService.InsertIntoReviewes(r1,r2,r3,r4);

        MessageBoxShow(Page,"FeedBack Sent.");
    }
}
```

And I want that when you hit a radio button value the value will pass into C# and will get into the function : InsertIntoReviews that put the r1,r2,r3,r4 values into Access dataset.

Note that Ive attached only quarter of the code since it is too long. Btw I closed the first form tag because it is only a part of the code (it closed at the end of the full code).

Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you.

$('input[type=radio]').change( function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'controller/InsertIntoReviewes',
         data: { radios : $("formName").serializeObject() },
         success: function(result){
         }
      });
});

Comment: Thank you , but Cant I do that in C#?